# Failure to recover grub2 after installing arch-linux

Tags: grub2

I am currently installing and and re-installing Arch Linux for learning purposes. As I don't have a secondary machine, I have to do it on my main one. The thing is - I couldn't find a way to avoid installing grub in the installation process of Arch.

That's another problem, but I fail to use `boot-repair` as explained [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Reinstalling_GRUB2) to make Ubuntu my default OS again. After installing Arch I get grub1 booting, and it doesn't have entries to log into my Ubuntu system, and I don't really know how to edit grub. I prefer just restoring grub2 used by Ubuntu.

My question is simple - how do I do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the output of boot_info_script? http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Install Grub2 in Arch and then add an entry for Ubuntu: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB2#Dual-booting

Comment: it could. I use grub2 from Ubuntu to load both Arch and Ubuntu 12.04, there is an option at the end of installation, you could choose not to setup boot loader

Answer (score 1):

Launch `grub-mkconfig > /boot/grub/grub.cfg` to regenerate the boot entries, which will normally have your Ubuntu entry, unless it's on a VG.

If that doesn't work, then boot into Arch, chroot into Ubuntu's root folder, and do `grub-setup /dev/XX` (which is your hdd, e.g sda or hda). This will restore bootloader of Ubuntu's grub2.

Answer (score 0):

The bootloader installation in Arch is one of the very last steps you do before the reboot.  You have the option to skip the bootloader installation altogether.  You can either skip over the step by going down to finish or if you go into the install bootloader step there should be an option to skip there as well.

Comment: Although this helps them avoid installing grub in the future it doesn't really answer the question so it seems better fit for a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score -2):

The question is neither about Grub2 nor about Arch Linux. Basically you want to recover Ubuntu  Grub loader. Follow the steps mentioned [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows)

Arch Linux is completely configurable and that includes the boot loader installation.